# Quartz 2.2.1, JMX jobruntime always -1?

Tags: quartz

Is it normal that in Quartz, for the JMX Attribute CurrentlyExecutingJobs=> [item] => jobRunTime always is "-1" while it is currently running, or is there some setting in Quartz to ensure the jobRunTime is updated appropriately?

(confirmed via jconsole, Mission Control, and jmx code)

Usecase is to track/monitor long-running jobs, and thought jobRunTime would be the appropriate path. The alternative path is "fireTime" + CURRENT_NOW calculation, but wanted to avoid extra calculation if it was already occurring somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chasing this around, this particular value is not updated without it being manually set.  Reviewing tools that monitor Quartz jobs, such as Javamelody, they have to calculate it every time too:

```
elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()- quartzAdapter.getContextFireTime(jobExecutionContext).getTime();
```

If you want to manually update the jobruntime value for long-running jobs to check the value rather than calculating it outside, you have to change *every* job you have to support this feature.  Here is a rough example that can be modified for your needs sourced from: https://github.com/dhartford/quartz-snippets/blob/master/update_jobruntime_timer_innerclass

```
 /**
 * inner class to handle scheduled updates of the Quartz jobruntime attribute
 */
class UpdateJobTimer extends TimerTask{
    private JobExecutionContextImpl jec;
    /* usage example, such as at the start of the execute method of the Job interface:
     * Timer timer = new Timer();
     * //update every 10 seconds (in milliseconds), whatever poll timing you want
     * timer.schedule(new UpdateJobTimer(jec), 0, 10000);
     * ...
     * timer.cancel(); //do cleanup in all appropriate spots
     */

    UpdateJobTimer(JobExecutionContextImpl jec){
        this.jec = jec;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long runtimeinms = jec.getFireTime().getTime() - new java.util.Date().getTime();
        jec.setJobRunTime(runtimeinms);
        System.out.println("DEBUG TIMERTASK on JOB: " + jec.getJobDetail().getKey().getName() + " triggered [" + jec.getFireTime() + "] updated [" + new java.util.Date() + "]" );
    }

}`
```